# JMeter - testing unique links taken from CSV file

Tags: testing, jmeter, load, performance-testing

I want to test unique link taken from csv file in Jmeter. I have a csv file with unique values - "value 1", "value 2" .....
For each thread, I need to append it as part of url(or path).

```
Ex: BaseURL: example.com
For thread 1, example.com/value1 
For thread2, example.com/value2
```

How can I do this in JMeter? Any help will be highly appreciated. I have created CSV and all. Just need to know how to take that value and set as part of path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Put your "base url" into "Server name or IP" tab of the [HTTP Request Defaults](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/why-its-so-important-use-jmeters-http-request-defaults):

   [image]
2. Configure [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) to read the values from the file and store them into a [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html)

   [image]
3. Use the variable from the step 2 in "Path" field of the [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler:

   [image]

That should be it, each thread will read the next value from the CSV file on each iteration:

Demo:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the perfect solution. Only issue I'm facing is that from CSV file it is taking only the first character. Is there anything to do with CSV file or any special config on CSV data set config?

Comment: I cannot answer unless I see first couple of lines of your CSV file and the CSV Data Set Config setup, maybe there is a delimiter character somewhere

Answer (score 0):

In [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) add `path` as Variables Names, use Sharing mode All Threads

In HTTP Request Path field add ${path}

Each thread will send a different path taken from CSV line